# Backbone - Execute route function before subroute's function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Having the following code in a backbone router, is it possible to make sure that when a user navigates to `#test/map` or `#test/images` directly, the function attached to the route `#test` is executed first?

The `invokeTest` function creates a parent view which has the container in which the subviews "map" and "images" are rendered. so i need to make sure that base-layout view has been rendered before jumping to render the subviews.

```js
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "test":                 "invokeTest",    // #test
    "test/map":        "invokeTestMap",  // #test/map
    "test/images": "invokeTestImages"   // #test/images
  },

  invokeTest: function() {
    //render base-layout
    console.log("test function executed");
  },

  invokeTestMap: function() {
    //render map view using element created with the base layout template
    console.log("Map function executed");
  },
  invokeTestImages : function(){
  //render images view using element created with the base layout template
  console.log("images function executed");
  }

});
```

right now i only get the console log for the subviews, the root function is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
  invokeTest: function() {
    //render base-layout
    createBaseLayout();
    console.log("test function executed");
  },

  invokeTestMap: function() {
    createBaseLayout();
    //render map view using element created with the base layout template
    console.log("Map function executed");
  },
  invokeTestImages : function(){
    createBaseLayout();
    //render images view using element created with the base layout template
    console.log("images function executed");
  }
```

Or you can do it like

```
invokeTestMap: function() {
    this. invokeTest();
    //render map view using element created with the base layout template
    console.log("Map function executed");
  },
```

Simply put you need to put the logic to be reused in a function and call it.

If you have to do this in large scale, in the `initialize` of your router you can identify parent-child relationships using regex and update the child callback to a function that wraps parent callback as well. (Or you can go even deeper into the router - There seems to be plugins that attempts to tackle similar problem like [backbone.subroute](https://github.com/BackboneSubroute/backbone.subroute).

Comment: I was using the `initialize` method to render the base-layout and it was working just fine, but now i have a login view, so i can't use this approach anymore. your second suggestion seems like the way to go, with the router having a reference to the base-Layout view, and only creating it if it does not exist already, does this make sense?

Comment: @randomguy04 Yes that's generally how I've seen any view's initialized in router

Comment: So, I've done it this way, works well, however i'm a bit concerned about maintenance since i have to call this new method that checks if the baselayout exists in every view that depends on it, just for reference i can't use this on the `execute` method (which is executed before route navigation) since not all views in my app need this baselayout and there's a login view, with that said you've accurately answered my question, thanks!